# How to set the userAgent of an iframe to load the mobile version of a website?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How to set an iframe's userAgent to mobile version just like Chrome devtool does, so that I can see the mobile version of a website? Does anybody know the trick? I search from google for a while, but some solutions seem to be out of date. Please help!